# How to update view controller dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to ask is there any way to update swift view controller elements(chart, outlets text and background colours). What I mean is I am on the first view controller where I am downloading data from server(JSON) and I am moving the user to the second view controller when the first request to the server finish, but the third view controller doesn't have data already, however the user is able to go on it. There is a loading indicator with indicates if the data is loaded already. I want when the data is loaded this view controller to be refreshed with the data. No matter that user is over it. Is there any way to do this.

Comment: I don't understand one thing, with which data you are populating your third view controller? With the first one's or something else?

Comment: other data, with is downloaded from the save server

Comment: So you are calling the webservice inside third vc right?

Comment: I want when it is ready to update the third vc with it, no matter that user I waiting on third vc

Comment: no, inside the first one

Comment: Ohh okay I understand, but why you are not calling the webservice in third vc only if you want to populate the vc with it? any specific reasons?

Comment: So, if the two webservice is called asynchronously or synchronously?

Comment: synchronously, the second one is called exactly after the first one

Comment: Do you want to send data from second viewcontroller to the third one? Are you pushing the third view controller with UIStoryboardSegue?

Comment: Welcome!   Please draw a simple diagram to clarify your question. It's currently unclear. From what I understood your the setup you meant is this: `VC1 - after network call finished → VC2  →VC3 (access values from VC1's network call)` Regardless please edit your question and include your desired setup

Answer (score 0):

When you get the data from the request, find the third view controller in your navigation stack and populate the data.

If the third view controller doesn't exist yet, I suppose you'd have to save the data in the second view controller and wait for the user to go on to the third one and give it the data to populate.

In the callback of your request to the server, it would be something like:

```swift
if let navCon = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    if let thirdController = navCon.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is ThirdViewController }) {
        // The third view controller exists, I'll call it and populate the data
        (thirdController as! ThirdController).setUpData(data)
    } else {
        // The third view controller doesn't exist yet. What should I do with the data?
    }
}
```

You also have the option of implementing a delegate or using the notification center.

Comment: can you please give me some more instructions

Comment: it is not giving me to access the methods of the view controller

Comment: Are the methods of the third view controller declared as private? That would prevent you to use them outside of the class scope.

Comment: no there not private, they are just functions without access modifier

Comment: Oh, sorry! Forgot to add the type cast! My bad. Just edited my answer to add it.

Comment: it is not updating the chart, I am using the danielgindi charts lib

Comment: `if let thirdController = navCon.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is ThirdViewController }) {` <-- about this. Didn't @Resr say that inside VC1 async call he pushes VC2? So at this moment VC3 isn't built yet. So that `if let` will never succeed

Comment: I'm assuming the petition to the server is async, so we don't know when will it finish and return, that's why I put an `else`, where the data should be put somewhere and used to initialize the VC3 if the VC3 doesn't exist yet when the server returns the data.